# Receiving a response from an unknown host in Python on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, configuration, request, raspberry-pi, broadcast

I'm developing an application in Python for the Raspberry Pi that requires some level of configuration for use. This configuration can be done by hand, but given the eventual placement of the Pi's themselves, hooking up a monitor and keyboard will be unfeasible. Thus, some level of auto-configuration will be required.

The configuration pretty much just sets some properties in the program before it begins being used, so ideally this configuration information could be delivered via a web response (the Raspberry Pi will always be connected to a local intranet via the eth0 interface).

However, the issue is that the webserver which will deliver the configuration data to the Pi has a hostname which is unpredictable. The server may reside at 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3, or 192.168.1.2 for that matter, there's no way of knowing.

I would like to try to use the broadcast address to essentially send a request to every host on the subnet and wait for a response that sounded right, eg with a 200 status code and some data that made sense. Then, knowing the host of the server, it could request the initial configuration data and continue.

I'm currently using the urllib Python module for my web requests but I quickly discovered that using the broadcast address to achieve this goal would be confusing, since I'm essentially sending out a single request but preparing for multiple (mostly bad) responses.

Has anyone out there done anything like this using Python?

Comment: Using HTTP on broadcast is, indeed, strange. It looks like you're trying to reinvent DNS or DHCP - have you looked at setting up a server? If you can't or don't want to use DHCP or DNS, why don't you simply send a broadcast with the current server IP?

Comment: In that case, if I had the server broadcast on the network, how could I use Python in the Raspberry Pi to listen for that broadcast and receive the server address?

Comment: You'd just need to open a UDP socket listening on the broadcast address and define a packet with some magic number and the ip. It would probably be preferable to have the server only send the broadcast in response to *another* broadcast (with another magic number)